# Como resgatar da base de dados nome completo e mostrar só o primeiro nome?

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela que me guarda utilizadores e os seus dados, o nome e guardado num único campo.
O que pretendo e pegar um nome da base de dados por exemplo César Sousa e mostrar na hora só o César
Eu estou usando Laravel 5.4 e resgato o nome do utilizador através de `{{Session::get('nome')}}` que e uma session que guardo na hora que faz login.
Queria na hora que pego o nome do utilizador no template blade me mostre o primeiro nome antes do primeiro espaço.

Comment: Mostre o código que já tentou fazer

Answer (score 1):

O que você deseja é pegar o primeiro nome antes do primeiro espaço em branco. Em PHP existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso.
A solução mais simples e mais comum para esse problema é utilizando EXPLODE (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Este método transforma uma string em um array, separando cada parte do array a partir de uma substring.

Exemplo:

```
explode(' ', 'Carlos Souza de Azevedo'); // ['Carlos', 'Souza', 'de', 'Azevedo']
```

Neste cenário, você deseja pegar o primeiro nome. Ou seja, você deseja pegar o primeiro item do array.

```
$nomes = explode(' ', 'Carlos Souza de Azevedo');
$primeiroNome = $nomes[0]; // 'Carlos'
```

Comment: Tive a testar eu estou usando laravel eu usei o explode ao mostrar o nome do utilizador que resgato de uma session mas nao funciona apresenta eu erro ao abrir a pagina